# Ajax jquery async return value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, return

how can i make this code to return the value **without freezing the browser**.
You can rewrite this with new method of course.

```
function get_char_val(merk)
{  
    var returnValue = null;
    $.ajax({   
                type:       "POST",
                async:      false,   
                url:            "char_info2.php",   
                data:   { name: merk },   
                dataType: "html",  
                success:    function(data)
                                    {
                                        returnValue = data;
                                    } 
        }); 
    return returnValue;
}
var px= get_char_val('x');
var py= get_char_val('y');
```

**EDIT:** *i need to have at least 20 variables get from php file at other times.*

Comment: I added some apparently-needed emphasis.

Comment: I've seen this question (or some variant) of it countless times. There must be an endless piles of duplicates. If only people could read a little more about programming with asynchronous events before trying to using ajax or any other async api/language...

Comment: Or at least understand what the word _asynchronous_ means.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not possible.
Javascript runs on the UI thread; if your code waits for the server to reply, the browser must remain frozen.

Instead, you need to return the value using a callback:

```
function get_char_val(merk, callback)
{  
    var returnValue = null;
    $.ajax({   
                type:       "POST",
                url:            "char_info2.php",   
                data:   { name: merk },   
                dataType: "html",  
                success:    function(data) {
                    callback(data);
                } 
        }); 
}

get_char_val('x', function(px) { ... });
get_char_val('y', function(py) { ... });
```

Note that the two callbacks will run in an unpredictable order.

---

You should modify your design so that you can get all twenty values in a single AJAX request.
For example, you can take a comma-separated list of values, and return a JSON object like `{ x: "...", y: "..." }`.

Comment: Correct, you cannot technically use a return value in an asynchronous request because the program flow has already passed the point of a "return" from the first method by the time the response arrives.

Comment: but what i should enter inside function(px) { <<here>> }

Comment: @Sonny: Whatever you want.  That's the callback that receives the value.

Comment: @SLaks so i don't need to enter anything there?

Comment: @Sonny: If you don't want to do anything with the response, yes.  Do you understand what this code does?

Comment: @Sonny: That's because it's _asynchronous_.  There is no magic escape hatch; you need to do everything in the callbacks.  Changing the design to use a single AJAX request will make it _much_ simpler.

Comment: @SLaks ok i will do that but it'll cause much lags in my game is it any other way to do this like other js module like super_jquery.js

Comment: @Sonny: No.  There is no magic escape hatch.  No-one said that AJAX is easy.  Why would that cause lag?

Comment: @SLaks Because of much data i think.

Comment: @SLaks i made new question i think you will be interested
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555508/get-all-values-from-mysql-then-make-variables

Answer (score 1):

You can not make variable assignments this way (async). you must set the variables in the `success` handler.

```
variableArray = new Array(); 

get_char_val('x');
get_char_val('y');

function get_char_val(merk)
{  
    var returnValue = null;
    $.ajax({   
        type:       "POST",
        url:            "char_info2.php",   
        data:   { name: merk },   
        dataType: "html",  
        success:    function(data)
            {
                variableArray[merk] = data;
            } 
    }); 
}
```

Once all of the retrievals are finished you can access the x and y variables by using `variableArray[x]` and `variableArray[y]`

Comment: **Never** use `async: false`.

Comment: sry i need other one to get value because i got 20 other variables to define

Comment: Then you'll need to come up with an array (perhaps with keys such as `px` and `py`) and have the success handler manage that like: `variableArray[merk] = data;`

Comment: @SLaks, was just re-pasting. Good catch.

Comment: That should be an object, not an array.

Comment: An array **is** an object that is used for just this sort of thing. What are the advantages to using a custom object instead?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are expecting  but you can set  async: true if you dont want pause in the browser and so what you want to do with px on success