# Multiple AJAX calls with errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to make a generic function that allows me to get data from different sources at the same time.

I based my solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555079/ajax-jquery-async-return-value/4555133#4555133) post, and ended up with this:

```
var servicesURL = 'http://www.somedomain.com/services/xml_proxy.php?url=';

function getExternalData(service, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: servicesURL+service,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'myfunction',
        success: function(data) { callback(data); },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus+': '+errorThrown); }
    });
}

getExternalData('data1.xml', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});

getExternalData('data2.xml', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Here's the code of the proxy I'm using:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo 'myfunction('.json_encode(simplexml_load_file($url)).')';
?>
```

It works fine when I make a single call to the function, but when I make more that one call (as I did above), I get the following errors:

parsererror: Error: myfunction was not called

Uncaught TypeError: Property 'myfunction' of object [object Object] is not a function

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: What and where the heck is `callback()` defined in this snippet?

Comment: Do you really need the jsonpCallback: 'myfunction'....if not then just remove it and try again.

Comment: @ZlatanO. the callback is being defined when the getExternalData() function is declared as its second parameter, which gets passed the data received by the ajax call when the function is executed

Comment: ah, yea,  I see now.. sorry! :(

Comment: @Peeyush Yes, I do need to call 'myfunction'

Comment: Have you tried putting the second request in the callback of the first?

Comment: @JeffShaver Thanks a lot, worked like a charm!

Comment: Ill post as an answer than. I am glad it worked for you

Comment: @JeffShaver is it because of the race condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the second call inside the callback of the first. That should fix the issues you are having.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-jsonp-requests-causing-errors