# Using $ajax to retrieve content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [fork of Pageguide.js](http://sprintly.github.com/jquery.pageguide/) to present some guidance on the use of various pages of my web app. This works pretty good, however at the moment all content for the guides are statically set in a script:

```
var guide = {
  id: 'jQuery.PageGuide',
  title: 'What can I do here?',
  steps: [
    {
      target: '#user-tools',
      content: 'Some static content here'
    }
  ]
}

$(function() {
  // Load the default guide!
  $.pageguide(guide);
});
```

I want the content to be retrieved dynamically using an `$ajax` call to the server, so I changed my code to the following adding an `$ajax` call:

```
var guide = {
  id: 'jQuery.PageGuide',
  title: 'What can I do here?',
  steps: [
    {
      target: '#user-tools',
      content: function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'user-guide',
          data: {elementId: '#user-tools'},
          success: function(html) {
            return html;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Although the `$ajax` call appears to work ok (I checked using the Chrome debugger and I can see the correct html being returned and no errors appear in the log), the guide is not updated with the html returned from the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You *can't return* from Ajax, just run some code *on success* right from `success` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work, content will contain an `XHR` object. You [can't return data from an asynchronous AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555079/ajax-jquery-async-return-value). You need to run the code *after* the AJAX has returned:

```
$.ajax({type: 'GET',url: 'user-guide', data: {elementId: '#user-tools'}}).done(function(html){
  var guide = {
      id: 'jQuery.PageGuide',
      title: 'What can I do here?',
      steps: [{target: '#user-tools',content:html}]
  };
  //rest of your code goes here       
});
```