# Variable scope Javascript Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following code:

```
Main.User =  (function(){
    var currentUser = ''

    var get_current_user = function get_current_user(){


        Main.Mod.do_ajax('home/get_user_pnp_id','GET',function(data){


            currentUser =  data.username;


        },null);

        console.log(currentUser); //Doesn't work. It logs empty string.
        return currentUser;   
    }

    return {
        get_current_user : get_current_user,
    }
})();
```

The 3rd parameter from `Main.Mod.do_ajax()` is a callback success function from my ajax call. However I cannot set `currentUser` inside that callback function.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I assume that `Main.Mod.do_ajax()` makes an async call so when you write the variable to the console the callback function has not executed yet.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: Thanks, guys. I thought at the first place that it's about scope but it seems that the asynchronous nature of javascript is the problem. What I did is just to track it every single seconds to know if the result has returned. Thanks to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your callback hasn't been called yet when the assignment is made since the callback is asynchronous. See [Ajax jquery async return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555079/ajax-jquery-async-return-value) and http://node-tricks.com/return-response-ajax-call/